# Using QT with OpenCV on Raspberry Pi (python)

Tags: python, qt, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have a program that processes video from a Pi camera and displays the result. For the processing I use OpenCV. Now I need to make a GUI.

I found [this](https://www.baldengineer.com/raspberry-pi-gui-tutorial.html) tutorial how to make a GUI with QT and launch it on Raspberry. I tried to import my program and assign the action button to run it. The problem is that I do not know how to display real-time video in QT correct since processing program based on loop which freezes the GUI:

```
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
```

The only way is to use threads? And if so how should I do it? All the instructions I found meant to completely rewrite the program.

It can also be not QT widget but separate OpenCV window that would open and close at the touch of button.

How to use Pi camera I found [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/) so my code is similar to this one.

I'm using python 3.4, OpenCV 3.1 and QT creator 4.2.

Comment: instead of a loop you should choose a slot that performs one processing (previously one loop iteration) and sends a signal that it has finished. Then connect this signal to the slot. => loop that handles events instead of blocking.

Comment: Why don't you use `cv2.imshow()` ? You don't need Qt.